# Xcode iPhone specific nslocalized string not working

Tags: iphone, xcode, string, variables, localized

In one of my xCode projects I want the App when it starts to select a random number between 0 to X and then it this number will appear in a NSLocalizedstring that will display a random sentence in a textfield.

But when I run the App, only the key is returned to me (introX).

Here is my code (in ViewDidLoad):

```
introNumber = rand() % 4; //Selects random number

textView.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:NSLocalizedString(@"intro%i", nil), introNumber]; //Put the random number right in the NSLocalizedString
```

All my introduction sentences are written that way in the Localized.string file:

"intro0" = "...";

"intro1" = "...";

...

"introX" = "...";

First, can we do variable NSLocalizedStrings?

Then, where is the mistake? ;))

Regards,

Comment: NSLocalizedString should encapsulate your stringWithFormat.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing to the wrong way round, first make the key for the translation then get the localized string:

```
introNumber = rand() % 4; //Selects random number
NSString *translateKey  = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"intro%i", introNumber];
textView.text = NSLocalizedString(translateKey, @"");
```

Comment: Ok, thank you very much. I assume your code works but I may have an issue with my Localized.strings file, because textView returns me one of the translateKeys possible (intro1, or intro2, etc...)!

Comment: That happens if the key can not be found.

Comment: I use the localized.string file to edit and store all the intro sentences of my app. Basically, my App is just in one language.

Is it the correct way? Because still getting the key instead of the intro sentence.. Thanks.

Comment: First the file needs to be named: `Localizable.strings` and not `localized.string` also make sure you add the file to the language that is the default language of you app.